# How do I select html injected from jQuery with Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm currently using Selenium IDE to fill a form.  The form has a select box for countries:

```
<select id="id_country">
    <option>Canada</option>
    <option>England</option>
</select>

<select id="id_province"></select>
```

The province options above is not generated until a country with provinces is selected.  jQuery takes care of that generation:

```
options = '<options>Alberta</options><options>Ontario</option>';
$('#id_province').html(options);
```

My Selenium IDE workflow looks like the following:

```
Command       Target           Value
select        id_country       label=Canada
select        id_province      label=Ontario
```

After Canada is selected, Alberta shows up as the default province but Ontario is not selected and I get the following error in my log:

```
[error] Option with label 'Ontario' not found
```

Does anyone know which Selenium IDE command I should specify to properly select a generated HTML from Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to pause while the thing loads, using a `waitFor` assertion, e.g.

```
Command                 Target                Value
waitForSelectOptions    id_province           glob:*Ontario*
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I've been trying other commands to no avail, yours works perfectly.